# Sharing translations between server side java, ios and android

Tags: java, android, ios, internationalization

We are planning to create native mobile apps to compliment our website, which is written in [java](/questions/tagged/java).  Our website currently supports a number of languages, and we currently have all translations stored in standard java property files.

What is the best approach to reuse those translations in native [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) and [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) apps?

- It looks like [Android supports `ResourceBundles`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) just like in server side java, but that doesn't seem to be the standard way of handling translations in android.  Android seems to use a string.xml file.  Are there downsides to directly use `ResourceBundles` and their corresponding property files in Android, or is it preferable to write a converter which converts java property files into Android `string.xml` files?  Or are there existing converter programs which do such a conversion?
- Is there a converter which translates [java `ResourceBundles`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) into iOS strings files?
- Is there some way to store translations in a common format which doesn't require converters to translate between the 3 platforms?

Answer (score 0):

The following open source tool (liveral BSD 3 license) will work for Android and iOS. I suspect it will also work for webapp and if not could easily be extended to support that:

https://github.com/scelis/twine

A blog on it is available here:

http://www.codesushi.net/blog/2014/10/managing-ios-android-localized-strings/